# Can primitive operations be faster than function calls in javascript

Tags: javascript

For example, is this faster…

```
var min = a < b ? a : b;
A[A.length] = v;
```

Than this...

```
var min = Math.min(a, b);
A.push(v);
```

Comment: Try it and see. May well depend on your environment. But it's almost certainly not worth worrying about except in extremely tight nested loops.

Comment: Unless you have an application that must perform millions of those operations over short periods of time, it doesn't make one tiny bit of difference. And if you *do* have an application like that, your time would be much better spent trying to optimize the algorithm instead of looking for little micro-optimizations.

Comment: In addition, none of that code will work because `v` isn't defined.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples, you are comparing different things, so measuring the performance might be inconsistent.

First off, the `Math.min` function is a strict numeric function, whereas the `if` is just a true/false decisional branch: no coherency checking involved.

```
let a, b = 3;
const x = a < b ? a : b;
console.log(x); //leads 3

const y = Math.min(a, b);
console.log(y); //leads NaN
```

About the array, the first form should be avoided. I think it is forbidden in strict mode (for obvious reasons).

Instead, if you seek performace in arrays, you should try to pre-allocate them whenever possible. For instance, instead of "appending" items, size the array to a reasonable length (large enough), and simply set the cells content. That should prevent hidden reallocations of the array (and that costs).

Solely to depict a possible scenario:

```
const arr = new Array(20);  //allocate 20 cells once only
let l = 0;  //allocate numeric variable (cheap)

a[l++] = 123;       //no allocation involved
a[l++] = 456;       //still no allocation
```